# Padding Bottom não funciona

Tags: html, css, css-padding

Estou fazendo a versão mobile do meu site, com duas barras (uma no topo com o logo e outra na base da página com links de contato). Essas barras estão com a posição fixed, aparecendo sobre uma lista ocupando 100% da tela. O problema é que a barra da base está tapando o ultimo item da lista. No topo consegui corrigir usando padding top. Tentei fazer o mesmo com padding bottom, mas não parece funcionar. Ou fica um espaço muito grande em branco ou a barra continua tapando o ultimo item.

Comment: Formule uma pergunta em que o problema pode ser reproduzido. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque estás a adicionar `position:absolute;` à `div` principal que contém a lista (`#source`), quando isto não é necessário ser implementado.

Como já estás a adicionar `position:fixed;` ao `#top-bar` e ao `.large-contact-sheet`, que são as duas barras de navegação superior e inferior, evitas de estar a adicionar `position:absolute;` ao `#source` que é o conteúdo principal, pois esta propriedade não é necessária e não está ali a fazer nada, juntamente com outras propriedades que foram adicionadas por causa desta propriedade.

Limpando os estilos desnecessários implementados no `#source`, eis como o código irá ficar:

```
#source {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    /* Ou padding-bottom: 50px; se preferires */
}
```

Só vais precisar desta propriedade no `#source` que é para compensar o tamanho `height` aplicado à class `.large-contact-sheet` que é de `height:50px;`.

Já que vamos na onda aproveito também para sugerir removeres outras propriedades da class `.large-contact-sheet` que são desnecessárias, principalmente os `overflows`, pois esta é a razão das barras de scroll indesejadas estarem ali a aparecer no final da página.
Com o código desnecessário removido ele ficará assim:

```
.large-contact-sheet {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #900;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Não sei porque negativaram...

Comment: @renan tinha sido o usuário acima "`25037`" que após a sua resposta ter recebido votos negativos,  ele entrou numa "maré de ódio" e saiu negativando não só esta minha resposta, mas todas as outras respostas/perguntas que ele conseguiu encontrar acessando o meu perfil. Mas já foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, use a propriedade `overflow-x: hidden;` para tirar o scroll inferior, e para o elemento que está sendo tapando coloque um `margin-bottom` somente no último elemento.

Comment: Apesar da `barra-de-scroll` no final da página ser o que mais se realça ao abrirmos a página do site, penso que não seja realmente isto que o Autor se refere e está a perguntar na sua pergunta.